# Exists a perfect square that divided by 6 equals a prime number?

Tags: prime-numbers, square-numbers

I recently took a test and a question came up that asked the question:

```
If n is a prime number, then 6n could NOT be:
A. An even number 
B. An integer 
C. A multiple of 3 
D. A perfect square 
E. A whole number
```

I was able to rule out all the options except D, but I felt like it was possible for a prime number multiplied by 6 to be a perfect square, but I couldn’t think of any possible cases.

Comment: $2\times 3\times p$, for a prime $p$, can't be a perfect square.  Hint:  Just think about what the prime factorization of a perfect square must look like.

Comment: Why do you feel like it’s possible?

Comment: The question asks if $6n$ could not be a perfect square. Even if it's not clear whether $6n$ can ever be a perfect square, you can see examples where it's not a perfect square (take $n = 2$) and so you have your answer.

Comment: I read “could not be” as a universally quantified statement. I think it’s $\forall n \mbox{ a prime} \; 6n \mbox{ is not a perfect square} $

Comment: What have you tried yourself. I mean, there already is an answer given below. But I have to ask: does any of it look familiar to you? What was the course on number theory on again?

Comment: Reading the question again, I can see how it could be read either way, so I think it's badly worded.  "could (not be a perfect square)" doesn't have the same meaning as "(could not) be a perfect square". Although in this case, the answer would be the same.

Comment: The others are obviously true about $6n$ so you must think like Sherlock Holmes. When you've eliminated all that is impossible then whatever remains must be the truth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$6n=2\cdot3\cdot n$

For this to be a perfect square, $n$ would need to have $2$ and $3$ as factors because each prime factor needs to occur an even number of times. Since $n$ is prime it could not have both $2$ and $3$ as factors. Therefore, $6n$ cannot be a perfect square.